# How to access ui-router $state.go inside angular factory?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to use `$state.go` inside a factory like this

```
App.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$log', '$window', '$state', 'stacktraceService', function ($log, $window, $state, stacktraceService) {

    // log the given error to the remote server.
    return function (exception, cause) {

        $log.error.apply($log, arguments);

        try {

            var errorMessage = exception.toString();
            var stackTrace = stacktraceService.print({ e: exception });

            // Log the JavaScript error to the server.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./api/systemMessage",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: angular.toJson({
                    errorUrl: $window.location.href,
                    errorMessage: errorMessage,
                    stackTrace: stackTrace,
                    cause: (cause || "")
                })
            });

            $state.go('error');
        } catch (loggingError) {
            // For Developers - log the log-failure.
            $log.warn("Error logging failed");
            $log.log(loggingError);
         $state.go('error');
        }
    };

    // Return the logging function.
    //return (log);
}]);
```

I am getting this error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%20%24stateProvider%20%3C-%20%20%24state%20%3C-%20%24exceptionHandler%20%3C-%20%24rootScope

Please help to find a solution.

Comment: Might be `' $state',` should be `'$state',` there is a space before `$state`

Comment: Are you sure about stacktraceService?

Comment: Also did you add ui-router module ?